# How to do linear interpolation for multi-dimensional arrays in Numpy?

Tags: numpy

Having problems to implement a linear interpolation in `numpy` that works for n-D arrays. I would like a simple solution working for 1D and also 3D arrays.

For the linear interpolation, I'm using `np.interp`, which works great for 1D:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
xp = [1, 3, 5]
fp = [10, 30, 50]
np.interp(x, xp, fp)
Out: array([10., 20., 30., 40., 50.])
```

Now if my `fp` has multiple columns:

```
fp_multicol = np.array([10, 30, 50, 100, 300, 500]).reshape((2,3))
Out: 
array([[ 10,  30,  50],
       [100, 300, 500]])
```

That doesn't work directly with `np.interp` since it can only handle 1D arrays:

```
np.interp(x, xp, fp_multicol)
Traceback (most recent call last):
blablabla
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

So I came up with a `for`-loop in a list comprehension:

```
np.array([np.interp(x, xp, col) for col in fp_multicol])
array([[ 10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  50.],
       [100., 200., 300., 400., 500.]])
```

But then that doesn't work for 1D arrays...

```
np.array([np.interp(x, xp, col) for col in fp])
Traceback (most recent call last):
blablabla
ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array
```

Any quick and simple solution that would work for both?

I'd expect `numpy` to have such interpolation function but so far could not find any.

Comment: i think you might want to `.flatten` and then `.reshape`

Comment: Your code works in my system. Try upgrading your numpy package. This is the output: `[10. 20. 30. 40. 50.]
[[ 10.  20.  30.  40.  50.]
 [100. 200. 300. 400. 500.]]`

Comment: @Ehsan are you referring to the output of which command? `np.interp(x, xp, fp_multicol)`?

Comment: @PaulH I've tried that but didn't figure how to handle `xp`. For 1D arrays `xp` would be unchanged, but say for 3D arrays, I'd need to repeat `xp` 3 times.